# Why aren't my 'epub.js', 'jszip.js' and 'jszip-utils.min.js' files able to load?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jszip, epub.js

I am developing a web extension that is to read and parse an uploaded **epub** file. Since the **Content Security Policy** for Chrome extensions restricts external javascript files from being linked to an extension, I have had to download the entire required `epub.js`, `jszip.js` and `jszip-utils.min.js` files and include them in my project. I also updated the **"web_accessible_resources"** with these files.

The issue I have now is that my code indicates that the above-mentioned javascript files fail to load when I upload an epub file. Following is my code. Focus on the `loadBook()` function that always gets stuck in a loop and logs out: `'Error: JSZip library not loaded, trying again'` repeatedly.

```
function loadBook() {
        if (typeof JSZip === 'undefined' || typeof JSZip.utils === 'undefined') {
          console.log('Error: JSZip library not loaded, trying again');
          setTimeout(loadBook, 1000);
          return;
        }
```

Find below the entire code which runs when I upload an epub file:

```
function handleFileSelection(event) {
   const file = event.target.files[0]; // Get the selected file
   const reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function (event) {
   // File reading completed
   const fileData = event.target.result; // Get the file data

   console.log('fileData: ', fileData);

   // Create a script element for EPUB.js
   const epubScript = document.createElement('script');
   epubScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('epub.js');
   document.head.appendChild(epubScript);

   // Create a script element for JSZip
   const jszipScript = document.createElement('script');
   jszipScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('jszip.min.js');
   document.head.appendChild(jszipScript);

   // Create a script element for JSZip Utils
   const jszipUtilsScript = document.createElement('script');
   jszipUtilsScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('jszip-utils.min.js');
   document.head.appendChild(jszipUtilsScript);

   // Wait for all scripts to load
   Promise.all([
     new Promise((resolve) => {
       epubScript.onload = resolve;
     }),
     new Promise((resolve) => {
       jszipScript.onload = resolve;
     }),
     new Promise((resolve) => {
       jszipUtilsScript.onload = resolve;
     }),
   ])
     .then(() => {
       // Both scripts are loaded, you can start using them here
       console.log('EPUB.js and JSZip libraries are loaded');

       // Create a new book instance
       const book = ePub();

       // Proceed with the book logic
       loadBook();

       function loadBook() {
         if (typeof JSZip === 'undefined' || typeof JSZip.utils === 'undefined') {
           console.log('Error: JSZip library not loaded, trying again');
           setTimeout(loadBook, 1000);
           return;
         }

       }
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error('Failed to load EPUB.js or JSZip:', error);
     });
 };

}
```

How can I resolve this or is there a better solution to this?

Comment: In addition to including the .js files in `web_accessible_resources`, you need to link each of them with `<script>` tags in the HTML file that will use them. See the `<script>` tag for `choose_beast.js` in this example repo from Mozilla https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/main/beastify/popup/choose_beast.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I linked each of the scripts to the body of the HTML file as 
 suggested by you. I am even able to see them in the HTML file, but I am still not able to run `loadBook();` function as I get the following error message: `Failed to load EPUB.js or JSZip: ferenceError: loadBook is not defined at`